# T-SQL + .NET - Как правильно приконнектиться?

Tags: c#, sql-server

В наличии:

```
string serverName = "ServerName";
string databaseName = "DatabaseName";
string login = "UserName";
SecureString password;
```

Использую конструктор

`ServerConnection serverConnection = new ServerConnection(connectionString, login, pass);`

Пытался комбинировать варианты для connectionString - так и не понял, как правильно. В примере на MSDN они подключаются просто к серверу, а мне то надо в конкретную БД записывать.
До этого использовал просто

```
        connectionString =
            "Data Source=" + serverName +
            ";Initial Catalog=" + databaseName +
            ";Login=" + login +
            ";Pass=" + password +
            ";";
```

И все работало. Появилось требование использовать SecureString - ступор.

Comment: Опять, мне не хватает репутации, чтобы оформить реплику, которая не тянет на ответ, как комментарий. Насколько я понимаю, Вы не можете извлечь содержимое из SecureString. Если это так, то посмотрите здесь http://www.cyberforum.ru/csharp-beginners/thread1728117.html

Comment: Задачу решил иначе. Просто приконнектился к серверу через конструктор с тремя аргументами: (string server, string login SecureString pass), затем проинициализировал переменную типа Database -> (string server, string db).